# Multilingual PHP Site with browser's lnaguage detection and Cookie

Tags: php

I would like to make my site multilingual. How can I simply include the right language file by FIRST detecting the browser's language and THEN by setting a cookie if the user clicks on a language flag present on each page.

I found this script:

```
<script>

/*
Browser Language Redirect script- By JavaScript Kit
For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit http://www.javascriptkit.com
This notice must stay intact
*/

//Enter ISO 639-2 letter Language codes to detect (see: http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/iso639.htm):
var langcodes=new Array("en", "de", "it", "default")

//Enter corresponding redirect URLs (last one is for default URL):
var langredirects=new Array("english/index.php", "deutsch/index.php", "italiano/index.php", "english/index.php")

var languageinfo=navigator.language? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage
var gotodefault=1

function redirectpage(dest){
if (window.location.replace)
window.location.replace(dest)
else
window.location=dest
}

for (i=0;i<langcodes.length-1;i++){
if (languageinfo.substr(0,2)==langcodes[i]){
redirectpage(langredirects[i])
gotodefault=0
break
}
}

if (gotodefault)
redirectpage(langredirects[langcodes.length-1])


</script>
```

Comment: You can't detect a user's browser language. It's one of the few things on internet where you do have some privacy with.

Comment: Really? I mean the browser's language set in settings.

Comment: I understand, but you can't. What you might want to do instead, is to detect country/location through IP-address, or let the visitors (give the option to) choose the desired language themselves.

Comment: I found the javascript i posted in my question. Doesn't it detect a browser's language?

Comment: I guess what the thread opener wants, is the language preference the browser sends in the `Accept-language` header. This can be used (and is also used by me) to give a first matching version of the website. Yet, do not ask me how to use it in Javascript. I’m PHP developer…

Comment: Yes, that'swaht I am looking for: the language preference the browser sends. And the code should show a site in that language first and then, if a user chooses a different language (little flags on each page) it should use the chosen language and set a cookie for it.

Comment: Well I'm no JS expert so I have no clue what above code does... But if you have the script, you can just try if it works. If it does then I'm horribly mistaken, but I have my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you what you want:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['locale'])){
    // See if the client headers tell us what language they want. If not, 
    // default to U.S. English.
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
        $lang = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
        $pattern = '/^(?P<primarytag>[a-zA-Z]{2,8})'.'(?:-(?P<subtag>[a-zA-Z]{2,8}))?(?:(?:;q=)'.'(?P<quantifier>\d\.\d))?$/';
        $splits = array();

        if (preg_match($pattern, $lang[0], $splits)) {
            if (isset($splits[1]) && isset($splits[2])){
                $_SESSION['locale'] = "$splits[1]_$splits[2]";
            }else{
                $_SESSION['locale'] = 'en_US';
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['locale'] = 'en_US';
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['locale'] = 'en_US';
    }
}
```